# nginx reverse proxy gitlab not working git clone git

Tags: git, nginx, gitlab

we have three gitlab servers behind nginx proxy, the problem is that when developers clone the repository over http, cloning takes place, and when they clone git clone git@..., an error occurs

```
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

nginx.conf config, tried to throw through stream, but the error is still like this

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 1024;
}

stream {
upstream ssh {
server 10.*.*.*:22;
}
server {
listen 8022;
proxy_pass ssh;
}
}



http {
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 4096;
server_names_hash_bucket_size 4096;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name _;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;

include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
}
```

and the site config

```
server
{
listen 80;
server_name bla.bla.bla;

location /
{
return 301 https://bla.bla.bla;
}
}
server
{
listen 443 ssl;
server_name bla.bla.bla;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bla.bla.bla/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bla.bla.bla/privkey.pem;

location /
{
proxy_pass https://10.*.*.*;
proxy_read_timeout 300;
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bla.bla.bla/fullchain.pem;
proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bla.bla.bla/privkey.pem;

}
}
```

I completely disabled the firewall on the nginx server, on the gitlab server, but that didn't help either.
the ssh key has been added to the gitlab profile, port 22 is being listened to on both servers. How to solve the problem?

Comment: This looks like some kind of ssh and/or nginx setup issue that would belong on superuser or serverfault. I haven't voted to close it (yet...?) myself though.